# Permission denied while accessing a file located in cache directory of an application from a separated foreground service

Tags: android, aidl, android-fileprovider

I am implementing an application that communicate via AIDL interface to a remote Foreground service.
While trying to access a file, created by the application in the external cache folder, from the service, I tried to send it as URI packed in intent via AIDL. I get the error bellow:
Permission Denial: opening provider androidx.core.content.FileProvider from ProcessRecord{8a6853c 852:com.app.service/u0a89} (pid=852, uid=10089) that is not exported from UID 10090

Code from the Application:

```
    Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),"com.app.fileprovider", myfile);
    grantUriPermission("com.app",contentUri,Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
    recognizer.sendFile(intent); // AIDL proxy call
```

Code from Service

```
    // AIDL sendFile stub body 
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    InputStream inputStream = null;
    String str = "";
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();
    try {
          inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
          Log.d(TAG, "FileNotFoundException");
    }
```

I adjusted the manifest according to the Android File provider guideline by adding in the Application manifest:

```
        <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.app.fileprovider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/file_paths" />
        </provider>
```

and file_paths.xml as bellow

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-cache-path name="my_files" path="." />
</paths>
```

Is the approach to share the uri intent via AIDL interface valid?
can the fact that my foreground service doesnt have any activity is playing a role here?
Any additional input/guidance here can be helpful.

Thanks

Comment: `Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getAppl....`. We do not know how that uri would look like as you did not tell the value of `contentUri.toString()`.

Comment: Also tell the value of `myfile.getAbsoluthePath()`.

Comment: Also tell the value of `uri.toString()`.

Comment: `android:authorities="com.app.fileprovider"` and `"com.app"` do not match.